# Dynamic type guard functions

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I would like to create a type guard function which checks if specific keys in an object have e.g. a `string` value. This is easy enough if I know the key names:

```js
const data: object = { a: 'one', b: 'two', c: 'three' };

function hasStringKeyA(data: any): data is { a: string } {
    return typeof data.a === 'string';
}

if (hasStringKeyA(data)) {
    console.log(data.a);
}
```

But when I need to check for more keys, this gets messy:

```js
if (hasStringKeyA(data) && hasStringKeyB(data)) {
    console.log([ data.a, data.b ].join(', '));
}
```

What I would like to do instead:

```
if (hasStringKeys(data, ['a', 'b', 'c'])) {
    console.log([ data.a, data.c, data.b ].join(', '));
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to write a type guard function which can be parametrized this way. Here’s a lousy attempt which does not work:

```
function hasStringKeys <K extends string[]> (data: any, keys: Keys): data is { [ k: typeof K ]: string } {
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (typeof data[key] !== 'string') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close. I would use a type parameter to capture the string literal type of the items instead of the whole string array. And you need to use a mapped type instead of an index signature, you could write it yourself (`{ [ k in K ]: string }`) but the predefined `Record` type should work as well:

```
const data: object = { a: 'one', b: 'two', c: 'three' };

if (hasStringKeys(data, ['a', 'b', 'c'])) {
    console.log([ data.a, data.c, data.b ].join(', '));
}

function hasStringKeys <K extends string> (data: any, keys: K[]): data is Record<K, string> {
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (typeof data[key] !== 'string') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDEAjAVgU2LAXhgG8ZUYBycHCgGhgzQqgHcQ6ZgmoALAJxw0YAXwDcAKHEBLAGYwAFDwQQAylD5SwAcwDSOAJ4R5iZPQDaFBBwoZrwCgF0AlE5LiYHzuAggANjgA6XxAteTN4JAQAhHoTKOBYyICMGAcArBBNeWsXCWFJGQBXMHwpcBglVXVNXQMIGAAeHRgcAA8oHDA4eugNbQA+BTi0BDB9egBrOrQdM2c0OJgpeoAlPBA+OCb6XprB4ndPGQ2FUEhYKf10OUuIVwPPR6W5eSh9AAccEDk4s0uHGAAQgIRAou20FHuhyeTwEUEKfDAMBkCF8EBwEhhHnyjxxnjhCKR6kKGPEwiAA)