# How can I write a user-defined type guard for a type discriminator?

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have objects that use a `_type_` property to encode runtime type information.

```js
interface Foo {
  _type_: '<foo>';
  thing1: string;
}

interface Bar {
  _type_: '<bar>'
  thing2: number;
}

function helpme(input: Foo|Bar): string | number {
  if (input._type_ === '<foo>') {
    return input.thing1;
  }
  if (input._type_ === '<bar>') {
    return input.thing2;
  }
  return 'N/A';
}
```

This is all well and good, and it works fine. However, I'd like to abstract the `_type_` check into a function, so that my call sites don't all have to know about this property, and they can just call the function instead.

```js
interface Foo {
  _type_: '<foo>';
  thing1: string;
}

interface Bar {
  _type_: '<bar>'
  thing2: number;
}

function typeIs(o: any, t: '<foo>' | '<bar>'): o is {_type_: t} {
  return o && typeof(o) === 'object' && o._type_ === t;
}

function helpme(input: Foo|Bar): string | number {
  if (typeIs(input, '<foo>')) {
    return input.thing1;
  }
  if (typeIs(input, '<bar>')) {
    return input.thing2;
  }
  return 'N/A';
}
```

The problem is, this doesn't actually work; I get an error:

```
't' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof t'?
```

...which makes sense. How do I write the syntax I'm trying to write?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnID6YAngA4SEBcyA5ADwyYB8tA3PsmABagDmARhoBnMFH4cAvrlyhIsRCgBCcKDk7FylGgwBGq1px78ATDRABXALa7oUmTAsgEYYOhBctASWEAKdDRwICQANFw6jCy0yAA+dPT6UKwAlDRYwMI4mhTUXJLqBFAQYBZQHlgAZBWeFOgw-snIALwtdOi6AFYQLtFVyOgAdNmUza1g9riOzq7uyNwQADZkVhC+oGQWYDQY6DEqUKnIouIgfLHIljbQBcjAMMi+pBQ+ayAbYGEMTOgpjXgEhWKpQ8602A2MpwEHAI0gIdweTwgL1BH3iiV+N0BJTKtzeYIhfBM0OQsOQRWxHloADkAPQAQXYuGkQA

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write a typeguard that checks for a dynamic type. Could something like this work instead?

```
interface Foo {
  _type_: '<foo>';
  thing1: string;
}

interface Bar {
  _type_: '<bar>'
  thing2: number;
}

function isFoo(o: any, typeEncoding: string = '<foo>'): o is Foo {
  return o && typeof(o) === 'object' && o._type_ === typeEncoding;
}

function isBar(o: any, typeEncoding: string = '<bar>'): o is Bar {
  return o && typeof(o) === 'object' && o._type_ === typeEncoding;
}

function helpme(input: Foo|Bar): string | number {
  if (isFoo(input)) {
    return input.thing1;
  }
  if (isBar(input)) {
    return input.thing2;
  }
  return 'N/A';
}
```

If you are set on keeping everything dynamic you could try a solution like this one,
[Dynamic type guard functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081948/dynamic-type-guard-functions)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your reply gave me an idea, which I'm going to create a separate answer for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the reply by DKidwell, I got the idea to use overloads to solve the problem (which I can create via code generation):

```js
function typeIs(o: any, t: '<foo>'): o is Foo;
function typeIs(o: any, t: '<bar>'): o is Bar;
function typeIs(o: any, t: string): boolean {
  return o && typeof(o) === 'object' && o._type_ === t;
}

function helpme(input: Foo|Bar): string | number {
  if (typeIs(input, '<foo>')) {
    return input.thing1;
  }
  if (typeIs(input, '<bar>')) {
    return input.thing2;
  }
  return 'N/A';
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution, though.